# Synchronized arrayList- incompatible types

Tags: java, arraylist, synchronized

I'd like to create synchronized ArrayList in JAVA. I've used this code:

```
static ArrayList<User> listOfUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<User>());
```

But NetBeans yells:

> incompatible types:
>
> required: ArrayList 
>   found: List

Any help possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collections.synchronizedList()` returns a `List`, not an `ArrayList`. Declare the user list as such:

```
static List<User> listOfUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<User>());
```

Comment: Not it says that type "List" does not take any parameters.

Comment: @user2721537 It certainly does. Did you import some other `List` than [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)?

Comment: indeed: I had java.awt.List
Thx ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
Collections.synchronizedList()
```

returns a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29). Use something like:

```
static List<User> listOfUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<User>());
```

Every *ArrayList* is a *List* but every *List* is **not** an *ArrayList*.

Answer (score 3):

```
static List<User> listOfUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<User>());
```

Should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.synchronizedList` returns a new `SynchronizedList<User>` instance, cast back to `List<User>`. If your declaration goes

`static List<User> listOfUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<User>());`

, it will be alright.

Answer (score 0):

`List<User> listOfUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<User>());`

Worked for me